# Budgie 17.10 garbled display

Tags: 17.10, ubuntu-netbook, budgie

After a fresh install of Budgie 17.10 on an ASUS Eee PC 900HA netbook, when the PC boots up the left 3/4 of the display is garbled while the right 1/4 is fine. Since I can see the right side of the top bar I can select Suspend and after suspending and a resume the display is fine.  This is consistent behaviour. Is there some sort of timing issue on bootup?

Answer (score 1):

My eee PC 900HA has Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.
And I solved it with this purely physical solution:

1. Turn on the computer by pressing the power button.
2. Quickly close the lid.
3. Wait for the leftmost green led to start blinking. Power led next to it will also be lit.
4. Open the lid and tap the power button to wake up the computer.
5. After a minute or so, the unscrambled clean screen appears.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on Asus Eee PC 1001HA. Solved by going to **Menu** > **Administration** > **xdiagnose** > *(enter password)*. Under "Workarounds", check box for "Disable bootloader graphics." Click **Apply** and close. Everything now boots properly.

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu 17.10 Install

Issue:

Desktop screen after boot is 3/4 black/garbled and 1/4 normal

Fix:

Restart PC, press Esc key to enter Grub 2 Bootloader Menu, highlight `linux 4.3` then key `e`
  edit Grub 2 `setparams`
  gfxmode=$…linux
  gfxmode=1360*768,1024*768,640*480

If your display settings are different then:

gfxmode=your*display,1024*768,640*480

Comment: This solution works fine at bootup. but how to update grub so you don't have to do this each time you turn the computer on?  I've tried modifying  /etc/default/grub (uncommenting the line GRUB_GFXMODE and changing its value to the EeePC's 1024x600, which works when editing the value of gfxmode when the GRUB menu is invoked at bootup)  and looking through /etc/grub.d/*, but can't figure out what to change.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on changeyourdevice.com's answer:
Ubuntu 16.04 install
Restart PC
Press ESC at boot
Press `e` to edit the 'ubuntu' line
*remove the gfxmode line*
Press F10 to boot