# Why is Ubuntu 17.10 booting up with a garbled screen?

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu, screen

I have an ASUS EEE 1005HAB netbook pc.  I have installed the lubuntu version of ubuntu 17.10 because it was recommended for netbooks.

I've used its previous versions with great success.  However, when I upgraded to 17.10, the screen became garbled during bootup.  I could still login, but I had to restart the computer a few times in order for it to display properly.

I had to hit Esc during boot, and select the advanced settings and select linux version 4.10. to bootup the netbook.

Will there be a update to take care of this problem?  Is there any other solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a couple of very similar posts such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971018/budgie-17-10-garbled-display)

These suggest that you will want to be running in an xorg environment (as opposed to a wayland environment) and then

- Install xdiagnose, by opening a terminal and entering

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install xdiagnose
  ```
- Start the xdiagnose package
- Select the checkbox for "Disable Bootloader Graphics"
- Click the "Apply" button at the bottom of the window
- Reboot the computer.

To run in an xorg environment, please see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)